# Invalid Sql statement error on when connecting Excel file with C# code

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to convert excel file rows into columns using C# code

```
string command=";WITH CTE AS(SELECT * FROM (SELECT IPAddress, Slot1,Slot2,Slot3,Slot4 FROM ["+ sheet1 +"] ) T UNPIVOT ( SlotPort FOR N IN (Slot1 ,Slot2 ,Slot3 , Slot4))P )SELECT SlotPort, IPAddress FROM CTE";
```

Am using above code to achieve the mentioned process. But I am getting the below error.

> Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE',
>   'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'.

Please anyone help to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Which connection do you use? Is excel linked to your sql server?

Comment: OleDbConnection am using

Comment: You are querying Excel directly using this SQL?

Comment: Yes. I am connecting excel with oledb connection using this sql query.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify unpivoted column.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT IPAddress, N, SlotPort
    FROM
    (SELECT IPAddress, Slot1,Slot2,Slot3,Slot4 FROM ["+ sheet1 +"]) T
    UNPIVOT (SlotPort FOR N IN (Slot1 ,Slot2 ,Slot3 , Slot4)) P
)
SELECT SlotPort, IPAddress FROM CTE
```